# Getting PDF from Json API response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf

I have a problem with the PDF file I get from the API in response to a Json GET request.
It does get a good string in Json, however, which makes the PDF file that appears corrupted. I tried to convert the response to a string but it didn't do anything.

Here is my code:

```
getPDF() {
axios
.get(apiurl + "api/Dok", {  params: {  }, headers: {  } })
.then(response => {
  const res = response.data.fileData;
  const pdfcode = res.toString();
 this.convertPDF(pdfcode)
}
)
.catch(error => {
  alert('error')
});
}

convertPDF(value) {
const file = new Blob(
  [value], 
  {type: 'application/pdf'});
const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
window.open(fileURL);
}
```

So if i'm import the pdf file from local and add it to this function istead of url in console i'm getting long string response

```
JVBERi0xLjUNCjQgMCBvYmoNCjw8L1R5cGUgL1BhZ2UvUGFyZW50IDMgMCBSL0NvbnRlbnRzIDUgMCBSL01lZGlhQ...
```

and PDF works, but when get it from URL i'm getting :

```
{"fileData":"JVBERi0xLjUNCjQgMCBvYmoNCjw8L1R5cGUgL1BhZ2UvUGFyZW50...
```

I checked it in notepad, the first answer and the content of "" are identical

any ideas what i can do?

Comment: None of us here have any idea _what_ your API returns, so how are we supposed to answer this? What is _“It does get a good string in Json”_ supposed to mean? “Good” how? Pleasant to look at?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. i've add response

Comment: What exactly does _“So if i'm import the pdf file from local and add it to this function istead of url”_ mean? Did you just substitute the `value` in your `convertPDF` call with a static string value? Have you logged `value` to the console inside of that function (in the non-working version), to verify it actually contains what you think it should at that time?

Comment: i import file by `import pdf from './file.pdf'` and change `axios.get( pdf, { })`.  sure, console.log(pdfcode) and in console response from api is ping not dark, this mean it's json ?